# Auto Stored Procedure Documenting

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, intellisense

I am trying to design an automated process to grab temp tables that are created, the columns that are used, the tables that these columns relate to and possibly functions from a set of stored procedures.  The stored procedures do not return a result set; they perform calculations and insert results into a set of tables.

I am contemplating using the results from Intellisense to aid with documentation because it can identify whether a string is a column, function, table etc.  I do not have any idea how I would leverage the power of this if I did have access but I would need to see what access I would have first.

Is there an API or a method to use Intellisense in a program or query? (By that I mean, does intellisense use tables/xml or similar to perform its operations).  I have searched online and not found anything that would point to a conclusion on this matter.  I have seen Javascript and VS extensibility but nothing for SSMS.

From what I can see, the only way would be to read the stored procedure in as a string and pull out the required details.

**Example:**

```
INSERT INTO TestTable

SELECT a.Column1, b.Col1, a.Column2, a.Column3, c.Col2
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b on b.ID = a.ID
INNER JOIN Table3 c on c.ID = a.ID
```

I would want to know that the test table was inserted into, the columns that related to each table in the join and their datatype,length,nullable etc.

Any ideas, criticisms, problems are welcome and open to discussion.

This process is not set in stone, just trying to design the concept of how it would be performed and may possible scrap all this but any help would be appreciated.  (Hope this is clear, I can only just about see what I am trying to make.  Need any further clarification, just ask.)

Comment: @lad2025 while your post you linked to is a good one the OP here clearly states there is not a result set so that isn't going to help here.

Comment: It will take you far longer to create a process to do this than it will to just manually look up the columns. You will have to do mountains of queries and against the system views (sys.objects, sys.columns, sys.tables...etc). It gets very complicated when you have an insert with a select like your example.

Comment: @lad2025 of course it is. I was just clarifying that since these procedures don't have output that examining it isn't going to help.

Comment: As Sean Lange said it won't be easy, remember also that your stored procedure can also have multiple paths (`IF THEN ELSE`), use `Dynamic SQL`,  `SELECT CASE ...`, `SELECT * ... UNION ALL ...`.

Comment: @lad2025, it is only one path, select case statements I do not care what is doing, just the columns related (i.e TableColumn = Table1.ColumnA or Table2.ColumnB).  Select * is part of the reason I wanted something that can already ascertain these values (but I can just remove select * and insert the column names since this is being used for laziness not ensuring all columns regardless of changes)  Thanks for the assistance from both you and Sean

Comment: @Sean Lange I understand the time to create may take a long time however, this is an idea to attempt and streamline the stored procedure documentation so the time to create is not a factor if it will prevent the need to manually document things in the future. The main part of the stored procedures will be inserts into tables.  I was hoping there was a way to take an arbitrary string and determine what it was based on some context that I could supply like how Intellisense works but this may be asking for too much.  Think it is better to scrap this idea?

Comment: As written, this is *way* too broad. It's also unclear exactly what the output or effects are that you desire of the "automated process" you're "trying to design". For example, you'd like to "know that the test table was inserted into, the columns that related to each table ..." – but *how* would you like to know that? By reading docs generated by your automated process?

Comment: @KennyEvitt In response to your question assume there is no supporting documentation for the stored procedure and the only input into this "automated process" should be the text from the Stored Procedure.  I.E. You input a created stored procedure and it outputs the various attributes I have discussed above.  I am not fixed on the _how_ at this point and more concerned over if this is possible.  Does not need to be focused on SQL and a third party can be used such as Powershell.  Currently, I am only trying to design the process in my head but I have no plausible ideas on how to accomplish.

Comment: You say that you want this for temp. tables, but your example isn't one. For a generic process, you could just take the select clause, remove any variables, add 1=2 into where clause and use select into #xxx and check the types of the table created. This will of course also require giving each column a unique name.

Comment: @JamesZ is the example not being a temp table actually matter?  I do not need to know just the type of table created, I could manage if that was the case.  I also need to be able to identify where the columns for that table came from.  All of this information, is more or less in the stored procedure and datatypes etc can be acquired in a different process, the issue is that a SP is just a huge string when you want the details of its process.  And in your example, couldn't I just select top 0 to get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a suitable question for this site because there's no succinct *and detailed* answer.

This is not impossible, and not entirely implausible, just extremely difficult. Basically, you need to parse T-SQL.

You can get all of the info about the database objects from the internal tables or views provided by SQL Server, but you're going to need to analyze the T-SQL code of the stored procedures to determine details about its behavior, e.g. the temporary tables it creates or the (likely) attributes of the columns of those tables. But if you intend on supporting dynamic SQL then this is going to be much much more difficult.

There is in fact a parser library provided with SQL Server that you can use (and even redistribute I believe).

See [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.aspx) for some details about the code.

I've actually got [a tiny library on GitHub](https://github.com/kenny-evitt/Transact-SQL-Helpers) that makes use of it for manipulating T-SQL code.

Another relevant link:

- [sqlparser parseresult - How do you parse?](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1135198-22-1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for that Kenny,  I will take a look tomorrow.  Much appreciated.  The dynamic SQL we use is not entirely complex and I could manage without having to take into account different paths because the only use is to paramaterise database name and schema name.   EDIT: Just took a brief look, yeah, a parser is a good idea.  No idea why I didn't think of it sooner but I should be able to make something out of that. If I pull off what I need, I'll let you know your help was not wasted.  Thanks again for getting me on a promising path.